# /users/{ID}/reputation is returning a 500 error.

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, users

The following API request:

> http://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/users/235/reputation?filter=%21DnBO_&site=askubuntu&page=1

...is returning an error:

```
{
  error_id: 500,
  error_name: "internal_error",
  error_message: "this error has been logged"
}
```

**However,** the error only occurs when `filter=` is specified. Removing that part of the URL causes the request to succeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fix for this has been deployed.